# Setting up LAN at conference network

Tags: networking, adhoc-network

I have a customer that will be going to a conference. They have apache application installed on one of the machines but will need to access it from another machine. Normally this isn't an issue when they are at their home network because they control the setup; but at a conference it is hard to predict how the network will be setup and if it will allow connections between computers.

Do you think if the conference has wifi would their be any way to setup a network between them? (Could I use ethernet between computers?).

The computers also need an Internet connection too; so we cannot just do an ad-hoc network via wifi. (I don't think).

What is the best way to have an internet connection as well for 2 computers to be able to communicate each other. (Client/Server)

Comment: can't you simply connect a cable between the 2 computers for your application and use the conference wifi for internet access ?

Comment: Options:

 1. Connect the two system directly to each other with a network cable.
 2. Bring a small switch and connect both computers to that switch.

Answer (score -1):

You could always run VirtualBox or Workstation and run one of the machines as a VM - unless your requirement is two separate physical machines.